# Upgrading to Ringtail 13.04 broke some APT repositories?

Tags: upgrade, apt, repository, 13.04

When I run `sudo apt-get update` on Ringtail, I get this:

```
Err http://overviewer.org debian/./ amd64 Packages
404  NOT FOUND [IP: 208.69.124.224 80]
```

and

```
Err http://overviewer.org debian/./ i386 Packages
404  NOT FOUND [IP: 208.69.124.224 80]
```

I went on the Overviewer channel on Freenode and asked them about the repository, and they checked and say there's nothing wrong with their end, so I uninstalled overviewer on my 12.10-powered laptop, and tried again and it works fine there.

Overviewer IRC snipet:

```
[08:54] <achin> on our server, i can see the file debian/Packages, but not debian/binary-amd64/Packages
[08:54] <achin> i suspect that something might have changed in ringtail?
```

Here's the (condensed) contents of my sources.list:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.5)]/ quantal main restricted
# deb cdrom:[Lubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Alpha amd64 (20130403)]/ raring main multiverse restricted universe
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130420)]/ raring main restricted

## Added by Seann 27 Dec 2012 - Minecraft Map Overviewer
deb http://overviewer.org/ debian ./
```

The instructions on [Overviewer.org](http://overviewer.org/debian/info/) are as follows:

> ### Overviewer.org APT Repository
>
> This is the Overviewer.org APT Repository, which hosts frequent builds of Minecraft Overviewer for use on Debian-based systems, such as Ubuntu or Debian itself. In order to use this repository, add the following line to your /etc/apt/sources.list:
>
> `deb http://overviewer.org/debian ./`
>
> Then, run `apt-get update` as root to update your repository information.
>
> Installing Overviewer is as simple as running apt-get install minecraft-overviewer. Since this repository is updated at the same time as the Windows builds on GitHub, you can also upgrade through APT. To upgrade, run apt-get update, then apt-get install minecraft-overviewer again.

And I've done all that, as you can see from my `sources.list` ... So... what changed between 12.10 and 13.04, and how do I fix it? It's not a REALLY big deal because I was able to download and manually install the update, but it's annoying to say the least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is a space in the `apt` line,

you've got:
`deb http://overviewer.org/ debian ./`

should be:
`deb http://overviewer.org/debian ./`

Comment: Thanks! Dunno how I missed that!

... Feel pretty dumb now though, but that's just my bruised ego talking. :P

Comment: It can happen to anyone to miss a nuance.